# Xcode 8.1 iPad simulator draws screen twice

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to bring my App current to iOS 10.1, using Xcode 8.1. My App is targeted to both iPhone and iPad.  All the simulators for the iPhones work o.k.  However all the iPad simulators draw a screen that is bad, and after a second, the good screen appears.

The bad screen looks like:

[image]

After about a second the actual screen appears.  It looks like:

[image]

This did not happen in earlier versions of Xcode, and I sure would appreciate some suggestions on why Xcode 8.1 is doing this.

Charles

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are still using a launch screen image file. Those no longer work. The initial screen nowadays is your *LaunchScreen.xib* or *LaunchScreen.storyboard*. You need to have one and configure it so that it matches your actual initial interface.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have a LaunchScreen.xib or LaunchScreen.storyboard.  This App was build several years ago and it was all built programmatically.

Comment: Well, that's the problem then. You now have to have one.

Comment: If that is so, then the iPhone code should have the same problem, and it doesn't. As I said, all the iPhone simulators work fine.

Comment: Whatever. If you think you know, why are you asking?

Comment: Also, there isn't any "launch screen image file".  The screens that I show above are all built with Core Graphics calls.

Comment: Yes there is a launch screen image file! It is probably called Default some thing... Anyhow. Make a new project. You will see that all templates give you a launch screen storyboard. I'm not talking about the main storyboard. This is the screen that shows _before your app runs_. That is what is giving you trouble here.